# Why are my classes not working properly? even though they work when only one class is active

Tags: python, class

so my classes won't recognize each other but when left to work alone they do work as seen in the consult printing at the bottom of the post. However the deposit and transfer are popping up the ram location, however, they do work fine when done separately just as shown in the consult action in the bottom part.

<function cashier.deposit at 0x0000023A9B656048>

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()


class account:
    owner = "name"
    pin = "1823"
    balance = 800

    def __init__(self, transfer, withdraw, deposit, consult):
        self.transfer = transfer
        self.withdraw = withdraw
        self.deposit = deposit
        self.consult = consult


class cashier:
    def __init__(self, withdraw, deposit, transfer, consult):
        self.transfer = transfer
        self.consult = consult
        self.withdraw = withdraw
        self.deposit = deposit

    def deposit(self):
        print("Please type pin to proceed")
        if account.pin == 1823:
            print("who would you like to send money to?")
        else:
            print("Invalid pin")

    def transfer(self):
        pass

    def withdraw(self):
        withdrawal = input("How much money do you want to withdraw? (there is a limit up to 10,000$ a day!)")
        account.balance -= int(withdrawal)

        if int(withdrawal) > 10000:
            print("withdrawals cannot be larger than 10,000 a day!")
            exit()
        elif int(withdrawal) > account.balance:
            print("your account does not have enough funds to complete your transaction")
        else:
            print("Transaction succesfull!\nPlease collect your money")


print('Today is', now)
print("Hello %s!\nWhat can I do for you today?" % account.owner)
action = input("Use commands such as withdraw, deposit, transfer or consult to continue!\n")

if action == "withdraw":
    print(cashier.withdraw)
if action == "consult":
    print("Your account's balance is %s $" % str(account.balance))
if action == "transfer":
    print(cashier.transfer)
if action == "deposit":
    print(cashier.deposit)
else:
    print("Uknown command, exiting programm")
    exit()
```

Comment: ```cashier``` is a class, not an instance.  So ```print(cashier.transfer)``` will print the function address.  You need to instantiate the ```cashier``` class.

Comment: and you're also overwriting the methods with what you're passing in to the cashier's __init__ constructor

Comment: You'd better study the difference between a class and its instances, namespaces, etc. The OO design is poor on a number of fronts. You need assistance on all of those in order to make your code work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various functions of `cashier` do not return anything, so the prints are just printing the string representation of the function. You could have the functions return a string like so:

```py
class Cashier:  # PEP8 calls for CamelCase here

    def deposit(self):
        pin = input("Please type pin to proceed")
        if Account.pin == pin:
            return "who would you like to send money to?"
        else:
            return "Invalid pin"

    def transfer(self):
        pass

    def withdraw(self):
        withdrawal = input("How much money do you want to withdraw? (there is a limit up to 10,000$ a day!)")
        Account.balance -= int(withdrawal)

        if int(withdrawal) > 10000:
            return "withdrawals cannot be larger than 10,000 a day!"
        elif int(withdrawal) > Account.balance:
            return "your Account does not have enough funds to complete your transaction"
        else:
            return "Transaction successful!\nPlease collect your money"
```

**Edit:** I removed the initializer, as these weren't doing anything. You need to instantiate your cashier with `cashier = Cashier()`, then call the functions of `Cashier` with `cashier.withdraw()`.

There's a fundamental misunderstanding on how classes work here (and OOP in general). You should read through the [Python docs on building classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) before you go any further.

Comment: Yes, but that is pretty hideous OOP on a number of aspects

Comment: @Pynchia Agreed. One shouldn't be building classes before one reads documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To use your classes, you need to instantate them like this

```
Cashier = cashier()//I don't think you should ask for the transfer details while instantiating. But you can do that by adding the parameter in the bracket
```

Now you can use the functions on the Cashier variable like:-

```
Cashier.deposit(deposit_money)
```

I think if you don't want to instantiate and want a function which does not actually store data, you can use a static function but I don't think that is what you want to do

Comment: Though conventionally the name of the *class* should be capitalized, and the *instance* all lower case.